# what is the use off adding ResponseHandler

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpconnection

hi what is the exact use of adding ResponseHandler, have a look at my code once

```
 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
          SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

may be it check response code like 200,400.. if so what they do for each resonse code thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[ResponseHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicResponseHandler.html) does not return status code, but it returns response body as string if response status code is around 2xx, in case your response status code is >= 300 [HttpResponseException](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpResponseException.html) is thrown